# Ansible cannot skip pause on first host from inventory group

Tags: ansible, pause

I have a playbook where I have to run a delay of 30 seconds because of a slow starting java application but I want to skip that delay in the first host from the group.

```
[jetty]
host1
host2
host3
```

I have tried to add a pause and skip the first host from group but it did not worked.

```
---
- setup:

- name: adding pause before running the playbook
  pause: seconds=30
  when: inventory_hostname != groups.jetty[0]
```

That should skip the delay from the first host but apply it on the second and third hosts, but it does not skip any hosts and applies the pause on all hosts from group.

Any idea how can I make this work?